# RecyclerView swap two adapters

Tags: android, api, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

I want to make an app which shows the last 15 match and next 15 matches using API.
I created a RecyclerView with 2 different list view. One for the last match, and the other for the next match. I've also created 2 different adapters, so when I click the different navigation bar, it will change the view(for example last match) into another view(next match). However, when I click the second button(next match) it force stopped.

I think the problem is in the Adapter set, but I don't know where

Here are my codes:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            //Prev Match
            recyclerView_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            fetchJsons()
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
            //Next Match
            recyclerView_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            fetchJson()
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}
fun fetchJsons(){
    //Json for prev match
    val url = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/eventspastleague.php?id=4328"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?){
            println("sukses")
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val prevMatch = gson.fromJson(body, PrevMatch::class.java)

            runOnUiThread { recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapters(prevMatch) }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?){
            println("failed request")
        }
    })
}

// Next Match JSON
fun fetchJson(){
    val url = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/eventsnextleague.php?id=4328"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?){
            println("sukses")
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val nextMatch = gson.fromJson(body, NextMatch::class.java)

            runOnUiThread { recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter(nextMatch) }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?){
            println("failed request")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I think you should rethink your design. why are you not using different fragments?, for the Last Match and Next Match. our use the old switching mechanism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what i will do, i will create two recyclerView and switch between them. and divide data from the API between them.

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                //Prev Match
                recyclerView_Next_Match.visibility = View.GONE
                recyclerView_Prev_Match.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                fetchJsons()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                //Next Match
                recyclerView_Prev_Match.visibility = View.GONE
                recyclerView_Next_Match.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                fetchJson()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
```